# where is the code behind implemented for this xaml

Tags: xaml, code-behind, autodesk, commandbinding

I have a xaml without a x:Class, this xaml has command bindings for some buttons. I want to add a new button and add some functionality to this button.

If I add x:Class, I get the error this class doesn't have the command methods.

How can I know, where are the commands implemented? How can I functionality to my button?

PS: I am working iwth the Vault Standards project from Autodesk

This is my xaml:

```
<WPF:MainWindow
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            x:Name="FileWindow"
            xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:CreateObject.WPF;assembly=CreateObject"
            AllowsTransparency="False" Background="#F0F0F0" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DynamicDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListValues}"
                              Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value, StringFormat=N}" IsEditable="True"
                              BorderThickness="0" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnforceListValues}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListValues}" SelectedItem="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value}"
                              BorderThickness="0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ListValues.Count}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value, StringFormat=N}" BorderThickness="0" CharacterCasing="{Binding Case}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Typ}" Value="DateTime">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value}" SelectedDateFormat="Short"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Typ}" Value="Bool">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value}" IsEditable="True">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="True" />
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="False" />
                            </ComboBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DynamicDataGridLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,3,3,2" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFABADB3" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ff0000" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFABADB3" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,1,0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,3,3,2" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFABADB3" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,1,0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Required" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="NumSchmCtrlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type WPF:DSNumSchemeCtrl}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,1,0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DocTypeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TemplateCbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CreateMode}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Templates}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TemplateTB, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,2,5" />
    </Style>
    <!-- This XmlDataProvider is used for defining Name/TemplatePath pairs that are used in the combo box "Document Type" and can be easily extended -->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="DocTypes"
                     Source="C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Vault 2020\Extensions\DataStandard\Vault\Configuration\File.xml"
                     XPath="/DocTypeData" />
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="grdMain" Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="grdGeneralProps" Margin="0"
          ToolTip="{Binding UIString[LBL73], FallbackValue='General Properties'}"
          Width="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="{Binding UIString[LBL8], FallbackValue=Categories}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="Categories" ItemsSource="{Binding PsList[GetCategories], Mode=OneTime}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding DynamicPropertiesCategory}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Prop[_Category].Value}"
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding UIString[LBL23], FallbackValue=DocTypes}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
               Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=DocTypeCombo}" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocTypes}, XPath=DocTypeInfo}"
                  x:Name="DocTypeCombo"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="DocName"
                  SelectedValuePath="Path"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding TemplatePath}"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  Style="{StaticResource DocTypeStyle}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding UIString[LBL9], FallbackValue=Templates}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" >
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFABADB3" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=TemplateCB}"
                                               Value="Collapsed" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
        <ComboBox x:Name="TemplateCB" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource TemplateCbStyle}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="TemplateTB" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UIString[LBL28]}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TemplateCB}"
                                               Value="{x:Null}" />
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding CreateMode}" Value="True" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F0F0F0" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        <Label Content="{Binding UIString[LBL10],FallbackValue=Numberingscheme}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"
               Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=NumSchms}" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" 
                  x:Name="NumSchms" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Prop[_NumSchm].Value}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PsList[GetNumSchms], Mode=OneTime}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                  Visibility="{Binding NotEditMode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding UIString[LBL31], FallbackValue=Number}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto"
               Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=DSNumSchmsCtrl}" />
        <WPF:DSNumSchemeCtrl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" x:Name="DSNumSchmsCtrl"
                             IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=NumSchms, Path=IsEnabled}"
                             Scheme="{Binding ElementName=NumSchms, Path=SelectedItem}"
                             GeneratedNumberProperty="_GeneratedNumber" Style="{StaticResource NumSchmCtrlStyle}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding UIString[LBL5],FallbackValue=Path}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"
               BorderThickness="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Prop[_FilePath].Value}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" IsReadOnly="True"
                 IsTabStop="False" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" />
        <Label Content="{Binding UIString[LBL6],FallbackValue=Filename}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"
               Visibility="{Binding NumSchmFieldsEmpty, ElementName=DSNumSchmsCtrl, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="FILENAME" Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Name}"
                 IsTabStop="False" Visibility="{Binding NumSchmFieldsEmpty, ElementName=DSNumSchmsCtrl, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <Button x:Name="TranslationButton" Content="..."
                 Grid.Column="1" Width="20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="24" IsCancel="True" />
            <!--  -->
        </Grid> 
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="DSDynCatPropGrid" MaxHeight="350"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicProperties}"
              ToolTip="{Binding UIString[LBL63], FallbackValue='Category Properties'}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="False"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="WhiteSmoke"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="WhiteSmoke" BorderBrush="Gray" MaxWidth="380"
              Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DynamicDataGridLabelStyle}"
                                MinWidth="140" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding DataContext.UIString[LBL64], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource DynamicDataGridCellStyle}" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding DataContext.UIString[LBL65], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid" Style="{StaticResource ButtonGridStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnOK" Content="{Binding UIString[BTN1], FallbackValue=OK}"
                Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand, ElementName=FileWindow}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotReadonly}"
                Grid.Column="2" Width="80" Height="24" IsDefault="True" />
        <Button x:Name="btnEsc" Content="{Binding UIString[BTN2], FallbackValue=Esc}"
                Command="{Binding CancelWindowCommand, ElementName=FileWindow}" Grid.Column="4" Width="80"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="24" IsCancel="True" />
        <Button x:Name="MyButtonCopied" Content="{Binding UIString[BTN2], FallbackValue=Esc}"
              Command="{Binding CancelWindowCommand, ElementName=FileWindow}" Grid.Column="1" Width="80"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="24" IsCancel="True" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, two ways to find where the .CS file is located:  1) add an event and have Visual Studio automatically create the event method. Visual studio will open the .CS file.  Once open, you know where it is located.  2) right click on a property and select "Peek Definition".  Once shown, hover over the CS filename and the hint will tell you where the file is located.

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work, Visual Studio says the event handler cannot be added. But your second suggestion did work !!! It took me to the definition of the Command, the Command is defined in a .dll, the "CreateObject.dll". Now I just need to see if I can externally extend the class in the .dll to add new methods there.